# All in one installers or Core + Plugin Sub installers?

Tags: plugins, build, installation

Build everything into one installable unit

- Pros

  - One package to test and deploy to all environments
  - All plugins installed but possibly not registered for use in the config
- Cons

  - Plugins may be in various states of the pipe how to deploy only good ones.
  - How to handle registering which plugins to deploy to which environment
  - Hard to change your mind might be a month between the dev build and the prod push

Build Core Installer (no plugins) + Sub installers (only the plugin)

- Pros

  - Smaller footprint to prod less room for errors
- Cons

  - Possibility of integration errors between plugins since they might be installed in various orders
  - How to rollback deployment when the previous deployment could be a strange assortment of core and sub installers.  Need a way to track what the specific installation contains
  - How to reproduce errors in QA when QA has all plugins and prod may have a smaller possibly older subset.

These are my thoughts on the issue I have been strugling to have my cake and eat it too but I seem to be stuck with these two choices.  Anybody else struggle with this issue and how did you resolve it?  Any other pros and cons that I missed?  So far I have chose the all or nothing approach but I am open to ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build everything is easier to test and to deploy. You, at build time and by testing, guarantee all the plugins are compatible with each other. Depending on nature of the product, you can create bundles of plugins, which can be selected during installation.

Of course, there should an option to remove the plugins from the installation package which are not production-ready yet. But ensure QA gets what comes to customers or shareholders.

With separate packages approach, you have to implement dependency tracking and so forth. It is more flexible, which results in lots of possible combinations.

I'd choose the first option: one single package with everything and ability to fine-tune the selected features/plugins.

There's also one more option: combination of the two approaches above. Consider Eclipse project: it has a common platform and plugins. One can download a package with the set of plugins which are usually used in a particular environment. Other plugins can be installed later, if needed. So you combine your core with several logically connected plugins; other plugins could be added to the installation later.